# Which wallets can send to native segregated witness output addresses today?

Tags: segregated-witness, address-format, bech32-address

Which wallets today are able to send to P2WPKH addresses starting with `bc1qf…`?

Answer (score 1):

[Electrum 3.0+](https://electrum.org) allows user to create a segwit wallet with native P2WPKH (Bech32 encoded) addresses starting with bc1q.. for Bitcoin mainnet.
When creating the wallet, select first "Standard Wallet" (as opposed to multisig) then "Segwit Wallet".

Comment: The question is about sending though, not about creating.